# Unexpected value 'Module in file' imported by the module 'AnotherModule in another file. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular

I've been banging my head with this issue for the past 4 full days. I think I've read almost everything on SO and google about it. So maybe, someone here will be able to help me out. I have 2 angular 11 libraries, one core and another called components. Components has a dependency on core. Core builds perfectly with `--prod` with no errors or warnings.

**The problem appears once I try to build components with `--prod`. Then I receive an error saying that all my core modules (I've got 3, CoreModule, DirectivesModule, PipesModule) have errors.**

The error is the same for all three:

> Unexpected value 'CoreModule in
> /Users/eestein/Documents/dev/main/projects/x/components/node_modules/@x/core/lib/core.module.d.ts'
> imported by the module 'FormModule in
> /Users/eestein/Documents/dev/main/projects/x/components/src/lib/form/form.module.ts'.
> Please add a @NgModule annotation. Unexpected value 'DirectivesModule
> in
> /Users/eestein/Documents/dev/main/projects/x/components/node_modules/@x/core/lib/directives/directives.module.d.ts'
> imported by the module 'FormModule in
> /Users/eestein/Documents/dev/main/projects/x/components/src/lib/form/form.module.ts'.
> Please add a @NgModule annotation. Can't bind to 'myDir'
> since it isn't a known property of 'ng-template'.
>
> 1. If 'myDir' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
> 2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("nConfig.isDropdownOpen &&
>    !!parentButtonConfig.dropdownComponent">
>    <ng-template [ERROR ->][myDir]="parentButtonConfig.dropdownComponent"
>    (a") Event binding attached not emitted by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the event name is
>    spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the
>    "@NgModule.declarations". ("
>    [myDir]="parentButtonConfig.dropdownComponent">
>     ") Property binding myDir not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the
>    property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in
>    the "@NgModule.declarations". ("="parentButtonConfig.isDropdownOpen &&
>    !!parentButtonConfig.dropdownComponent">
>    [ERROR ->]<ng-template [myDir]="parentButtonConfig.dropdownComponent"
>    ")

Here's the code for the directives module and one directive:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        MyDirDirective
    ],
    exports: [
        MyDirDirective
    ]
})
export class DirectivesModule { }

@Directive({
    selector: '[myDir]',
    exportAs: 'myDir'
})
export class MyDirDirective
```

Here's how I export everything:

```
+ src
|--- lib
|--+ directives
|  |-- index.ts: export * from './public-api';
|  |-- public-api.ts: 
|  |       export * from './directives.module';
|  |       export * from './my-dir.directive';
|  |-- directives and module
|--- index.ts: export * from './public-api';
|--- public-api.ts: export * from './directives/index';
```

And this is how I install the core lib into components (part of components' build process):

`npm install file:core.tgz --no-save`

Here's just a portion of everything I've read/tried so far:
[image]

Just to narrow it down a little bit:

1. I don't think it's related to barrel files, ever since my very first angular 2+ lib (2017), I always refer to the index file: `path/inner-path/index`. But I re-validated the whole code.
2. I also don't think I'm importing providers in the `imports` section or anything that's not a module, I re-validated the whole code more than once, just in case.
3. As one of the last things I tried before posting here, I removed everything from my core module (the forRoot method) and it also didn't work (solution posted here https://codewithstyle.info/creating-angular-npm-packages-with-ng-packagr/)

Using `enableIvy: true` removes the error, but it prevents me from publishing to NPM.

**UPDATE**

I migrated to v11.2.7 and tried to use the new combo:

```
"enableIvy": "true",
"compilationMode": "partial"
```

that should have allowed the build to work. Weirdly enough, I still got the error:

`ERROR: Trying to publish a package that has been compiled by Ivy. This is not allowed.`

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: have you defined in **tsconfig.json** path to your core library?

Comment: @vitaliykotov hi, no, but that shouldn't be required since I'm installing it with npm, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as answer so it's visible and because it does "answer" the question.

It was not related to how I exported or my files, whatsoever. The error was completely misleading. The error didn't even happen at the directive pinpointed in the message. There was cyclic dependency happening on another directive that was not caught by the compiler (`ng build --prod`), which is surreal to me. I had to go by changing several lines of code in several different places to narrow the problem to what it actually was.

I'm creating a repo so I can file a bug with the angular team.

It's pretty sad that the first build (which was the one with the error) was built correctly and only when I tried to build the consumer I received the error.

Anyway, moving on now.